# Reference types in Cadence

Tags: onflow-cadence

I have been messing around with types, specifically reference types, using the flow playground [ft tutorial](https://play.onflow.org/f5f2e5f5-375d-4ebd-a1bf-547279a2ae6b?type=tx&id=d510c23b-672d-499f-b916-04783a2a4d1a&storage=none) and I came up with a doubt.
References are supposed to have their own type, a reference to the referenced resource type; e.g for a `@Collectible` resource whose type will be `<A.0...01.Collectible>()` a reference to that resource `&Collectible` I was expecting something like `<&A.0..01.Collectible>()` but when calling the getType() function on a reference I get the same type that I get when calling said function on the referenced resource.

To clarify, this code... (that can be found on the line 32 of the transaction "Transfer tokens" on the link above)

`log(self.temporaryVault.getType())`

`log(receiverRef.getType())`

`log(self.temporaryVault.getType() == receiverRef.getType())`

...I get this output

- Type<A.0000000000000002.ExampleToken.Vault>()
- Type<A.0000000000000002.ExampleToken.Vault>()
- true

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accesses on references always automatically dereference the reference – operations are performed on the referenced value, not the reference.

Accesses are e.g.:

- Member accesses, accessing fields and functions, like `ref.field` or `ref.func()`
- Indexing accesses, like `ref[0]`

Answer (score 2):

This one is little hard to explain, but in my understanding: references are just proxies to the object.

So when you actually call `getType()`, you are actually calling it on the referenced object.